# SearchView or EditText is better for search bar function?

Tags: android, android-layout

I wanted to know whether using the SearchView widgit or the EditText widgit with a Button widgit was a better implementation of a search bar I wanted to create (a search bar meaning you type in a word and u click go and it'll take you to some sort of result).

Comment: Personal preference, I think. I always use `EditText` since I like to have full control over the components.

Answer (score 0):

Its depends on your requirement of your database is huge that the hint results cant be displayed in single screen then better to use edit-text with a go button for search.if you have limited data in list-view or something you can use edit search box.